# Do I really have to remove a second, hidden form field from within a label for my HTML to validate?

Tags: forms, html, w3c, w3c-validation

We have the following code in which we are getting errors in the w3c validator for "Any input descendant of a label element with a for attribute must have an ID value that matches that for attribute." and "The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant."  Is this something that should just be ignored by the validator (as it is seeminlgly correct) or should it be changed to appease the w3c? Note this is html5 doctype.

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="user_is_subscribed">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[is_subscribed]">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[is_subscribed]" id="user_is_subscribed">
    Newsletter Signup
  </label>
  <span class="checkLabel">We will never spam or give away your information</span>
</fieldset>
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Can this really be answered? Especially with HTML5 validation still being a little volatile. It seems more opiniony than facty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Labels should contain at most one input element. Move the hidden input out of the label. Also, when an input is a descendant of a label, the `for` attribute is superfluous.

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[is_subscribed]">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[is_subscribed]" id="user_is_subscribed">
    Newsletter Signup
  </label>
  <span class="checkLabel">We will never spam or give away your information</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: “when an input is a descendant of a label, the for attribute is superfluous” — logically, yes, but I believe some screen-readers need the `for` attribute even when the form element is nested inside the label, otherwise they don’t do the association. (This is just second-hand hearsay though — delighted to hear evidence to the contrary.)

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not very familiar with accessibility standards.

Comment: oh, I don’t think the standards mention anything about it. Just a bit of (quite possibly out-of-date) web developer lore I’ve had knocking around in my head for years.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this something that should just be ignored by the validator

No

> (as it is seeminlgly correct)

It isn't

> or should it be changed

Yes

> to appease the w3c?

No. It should be changed because it is wrong, and browsers have to error correct to figure out which element the label is associated with.

The label isn't labeling the hidden input, move it elsewhere.